# Angular - Argument of type is not assignable to parameter

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

TypeScript shows me below erros in app.component.ts:

> Argument of type '(events: Event[]) => void' is not assignable to
>   parameter of type '(value: Event[]) => void'.
>
> Types of parameters
>   'events' and 'value' are incompatible.
>
> Type 'Event[]' is not assignable to type 'import("/home/src/app/models/event.interface").Event[]'.
>
> Type 'Event' is missing the following properties from type 'Event': _id, name, date

Here is my code:

**event.interface.ts**

```
export interface Event{
    _id: string;
    name: string;
    date: Date;
}
```

**app.service.ts**

```
  getEvents(): Observable<Event[]> {
    return this.http.get<Event[]>('www.example.com/your-events')
  }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.appService.getEvents().subscribe(
      (events: Event[]) => {
        this.promotersEvents = events;
      }
    )
  }
```

What is wrong with my code? Thanks for advice!

Comment: Just a wild guess that your interface overlapping with the Angular's type event, I would try to change the name of your interface

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably forgot to import the `Event` interface in `app.service.ts` or in `app.component.ts` and one of the `Event` you are referring to is the native Javascript `Event`.

If that doesn't help, try to rename the interface so it doesn't conflict with Ecmascript definition files.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to import interface into app.service.ts. My IDE don't showed me notification about missing import. Thanks for advice.