# Error while iterating over an interface in the template - Angular8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I'm new to Angular 8.
I have a small component that takes an interface as input. The interface in turn is made up of three string fields.
I ran the build command `npm run build:gh-pages`, which reports the following error:

```
ERROR in src/app/components/bibliography/bibliography-item/bibliography-item.component.html(1,4): Argument of type 'BibliographicCitation' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Map<unknown, unknown>'.
  Type 'BibliographicCitation' is missing the following properties from type 'Map<unknown, unknown>': clear, delete, forEach, get, and 8 more.
```

This is my component `.ts` file:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { BibliographicCitation } from 'src/app/services/xml-parsers/bibliography-parser.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'evt-bibliography-item',
  templateUrl: './bibliography-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bibliography-item.component.scss']
})

export class BibliographyItemComponent {
  @Input() biblField: BibliographicCitation;
}
```

And this is my component `.html` file:

```
<p *ngFor="let biblEl of biblField | keyvalue">
  <em class="biblCitation">
    {{ biblEl.value }}
  </em>
</p>
```

**EDIT:**
each `biblField` output:
[image]

I hope it is nothing serious.

Comment: Can you post the value/json of **biblField**

Comment: I think your error is similar to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900906/11719787, Is it ?

Comment: @SameerKhan no I do not think so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Use an array, Luke!*

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BibliographicCitation } from 'src/app/services/xml-parsers/bibliography-parser.service';

export class BibliographyItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() biblField: BibliographicCitation;

  templateBiblCitData;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.templateBiblCitData = Object.values(this.biblField);
  }
}
```

```
<p>
  <em *ngFor="let biblEl of templateBiblCitData" class="biblCitation">
    {{ biblEl }}
  </em>
</p>
```

Comment: I downvoted your answer but then noticed you posted the question too, so I removed the downvote. The problem here is that it doesn't solve the issue, it's merely a workaround.

Comment: When I tried it it worked, and it is still used in my code base. It's clearly a simple solution to a simple problem. It depends on what you have to do.

Comment: Anyway, the problem stems from the fact that interfaces are extensible, while type aliases are not. [This](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300) is the related issue on the TS repo, but I think the definition of `keyvalue` has to be improved. Ciao e salutami Pisa! 

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem simply letting my custom interface extend Map interface. In your case:

```
export interface BibliographicCitation extends Map<string, string> {
    key1: string;
    key2: string;
    key3: string;
}
```